# Displaying 3D Textured models in Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures

I am new to opengl, and I followed some tutorial on the internet. I Can load 3D models, and display them with a **2D texture** wrapped on them... I would like to be able to create a 3D textured model in blender, and export it to my opengl program, so I would have the exact same model with the same 3D texture on it. I know It has something to do with uvs, and texture models but I cannot find out what.... Can anyone help me, suggest a tutorial, or make a special texture loader for me (in C++ if possible )? 
PS: again, I now how to load 2D textures, and wrap them on a 3D model, but that Is not what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the .obj format to import models from blender. You need to write some kind of obj Loader. There are tons of tutorials on how to accomplish that. But in a nutshell you need to load the positions, indices, normals, etc. From an .obj file.

I would just watch this whole series.
(Or for your needs the last video)

https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXT9T-hD0Bj31DSnwio-ywh

In the last video he also shows how to use an .obj Loader. And also a texture loader is provided in this tutorial.

If you want to export the texture specified in blender theres a line in the .obj file which contains the path to the texture. So you could load from that.

Comment: This is the tutorial I watched ! Problem is I don't want to wrap a 2D texture on a 3D Model like him; i want to use **3D textures** on game objects, so it looks "normal" !

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/3D_Texture Try this one. But i'm not sure if you can create 3D textures in blender. Is there a specific reason to use a 3D texture other than just make it look like its coming out of the mesh?

Comment: I don't know if I need them…. The problem is that in benny's tutorial, the texture is sort of randomly wrapped around the mesh; Does it have to do something with reading Uvs from blender ? Then I just have to export the texture from blender, read the Uvs, and It should be good ! Question is how can I use textures in blender, and how can I export them ? PS: for the loader I just decided to go with ASSIMP.

Comment: I have no idea how to use textures in blender. But just export to .obj file and you will have Uvs. Yes, the textureCoordinates decide how the texture gets wrapped on the mesh. It's not done randomly as you presume, theres a glm::vec2 texCoords in the tutorial.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I guess if i want to get 3d effets,  i can always use normal mapping :)

Comment: @MattMatt Textures are generally 2D images, like so: http://img182.imageshack.us/img182/9164/fireborninfantrybodyskiis9.jpg. It's the texture coordinates (aka UVs) that determine how they map from the 3D object space to 2D texture space. You can get 3D kind of effects with bump maps and normal maps, but the textures themselves will be 2D images. With something like Blender, typically you create the UV coordinates in the software (ex: using unwrapping with seam edges) and then paint the 2D texture in Photoshop or another digital painting software...

Comment: @MattMatt Some let you paint the model directly in 3D (ZBrush, Mudbox, Substance Painter, 3D coat, etc), but the end result is still one or more 2D images and UVs.

Comment: OK, That ' s what  i want ! Paint the model; but how do i get the generated texture?

Comment: Solved ! Unwrap texture in blender, then export UV layout !